# Bulk user delete with same email

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, bulk

I want to delete all users who have the email address of `@trash-mail.com`

How can I do that with a SQL? I'm trying this

```
DELETE from users    
WHERE email LIKE %trash-mail.com
```

But it's not working and I really need to be able to delete mass accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot quotes:

```
DELETE FROM users    
WHERE email LIKE '%trash-mail.com'
```

See http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php for more information on the `LIKE` condition.